# Mockito.doThrow().when .... Not working well

Tags: exception, junit, mockito, throw

I'm working with JUnit and Mockito to make some unitary tests. I want to handle the excepcion by using the **Mockito.doThrow()**  and I've already made use of it in another tests and it worked the finest way possible. 
Now I have:

```
Assigned newAssigned  = new Assigned();

      Mockito.doThrow(new SdkFault()).when(Api).addLicenseAssigned("2144", newAssigned  );
```

and when I run the test while making debugging of it when I find this

```
   Api.addLicenseAssinged(licenseId, newAssigned);
```

It should get the excepcion and throw it me right? Or am I making something wrong?
And I'm not mocking static methods.

Comment: what is Api, is it a class or class isntance? addLicenseAssigned is a static method?

Comment: @pvpkiran Api is a class but I don't have access to him unless I uncompile the code because its an api to comunicate with the server. But I think that It doesn't even matter because we never reach the code taking into account that we automatically say "when the method xxxx is called return the exception SdkFault()"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: Please rework your question. Dont put information here or there in comments. Instead provide a real [mcve] **within** your question. And follow java naming conventions. Variables go `camelCase`. By naming an object `Api` instead of `api` you are creating that you want to mock a **static** method call - which is not possible with Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the stubbing you are using is trying to match against an object you have created in your test and so it is not the same object that is called in your class under test, namely:

```
Assigned newAssigned  = new Assigned();
```

To solve this you should use matchers instead for your stubbing i.e.:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new SdkFault()).when(Api)
   .addLicenseAssigned(Matchers.eq("2144"), Matchers.any(Assigned.class));
```

Comment: I'm not mocking static methods! I'm working with an Api wich code I can't see, it only provides the methods for me to connect with the server. Like an webservice. That's why I'm wondering why is this happening. Thanks for your time in advance and I aprecciate all the help you can provide me.

Comment: I assumed it was static because. 1. It starts with a capital letter which should not be used for class instances. 2. You said it was a class not an object (i.e. a class instance). Can you show the code where you instatiate Api then?

Comment: @Mock
  private LicenseApi licenseApi;

Mockito.when(protexServer.getLicenseApi()).thenReturn(licenseApi);

Comment: Ok, final question. Can you provide the code where you are actually calling the class under test and is newAssigned passed to this method?

Comment: I'm calling the call under test when I created the test class and I don't undrstand what you want by saying "is newAssigned passed to this method".. Thank you one more time for your time.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's working now and I've been going crazy bout this. Thank you very much.